# include file for SQL from Classic ASP to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic

When I wrote this C# application using Classic ASP, I had an include file like this:

```
<%
string groupItemTable = "GroupCustomer"
string itemTable = "Customer"
string itemID = "CustomerID"
string itemColumn1 = "CustomerName"
string itemColumn2 = "CustomerAddress"
%>
```

After moving to ASP.NET, I've been told that include files are bad. I am writing this C# application in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web and am using `SqlDataSource` to populate `DropDownList` and `Gridview`. How would I go about incorporating what I originally used for Classic ASP to ASP.NET? An example of how I did it in Classic ASP was something like this (this was done in VB at the time):

```
selectGroupsSQL = "SELECT " & itemTable & "." & itemID & "," & itemColumn1 & "," & itemColumn2 & " FROM " & itemTable & " inner join " & groupItemTable & " on " & groupItemTable & "." & itemID & " = " & itemTable & "." & itemID & "
```

Comment: **warning** your code is asking for sql injection attacks!

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to access a database via .NET code.  As Daniel pointed out, directly writing user input to a SQL statement is dangerous, even if .NET controls sanitize user input (you haven't told us whether these parameters are coming from .NET controls).  There are options ranging from the .NET SQL Client to Entity Framework, and it's hard to say which is best without more info.

Answer (score 0):

ASP classic is a 1990s technology which has been discontinued since 2000.

To make it worse your code is exposing you to SQL injection.

On top of that this is not VB from the .net framework this is actually VBscript.

As you have been told includes are bad, it was a messy way to modularize and reuse your code and logic.

Fortunately you have made the move to ASP.NET and now you are using Visual Studio 2013.

So do yourself a favor forget the dangerous and obselete code you wrote and make use of the great Tool VS2013 and code your project the OOP way using classes and all the other concepts.

If you are asking for the proper way to query your database, you can use ADO.NET for instance, and make sure you use parameterised queries.